# passing the result of if statement/ conditional operator in function call java

Tags: java

how to do such a statement in java:

```
return BTT(Arrays.asList(Lmax))+BTT(Dinerlist.remove(Lmax))==1?Dinerlist:1);
```

BTT function call, if I am able to remove Lmax from Dinerlist, i want to pass Dinerlist, else I want to pass 1 (as list ofcourse)

also please comment in case of using the result of if-else statements in function call.

Comment: Why are you trying to smash this all into one line? Just break it out into multiple lines.

Comment: i am jealous that you can do this in python :-)

Comment: You can do it in Java. List.remove() returns a boolean, not an int. What is the return type of BTT?

Comment: @pbabcdefp it returns int

Comment: Ok, then `return BTT(Arrays.asList(LMax)) + BTT(DinnerList.remove(LMax) ? DinnerList : Arrays.asList(1));` should work.